# Bootstrap Modal issue with inputs and h5

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

So where it says in the button `data-whatever="Add a recipe"` I beleive this overrides my place holders for my input tags and im not sure why, if i get rid of this it will work but the h5 new recipe header will be blank

```html
<button id="button" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="Add a recipe">Add a recipe</button>
<!-- end of button -->

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">New Recipe</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form class="recipe-form" action="/pizza" method="POST">
          <a id="userId" data-id=<%=user.id %>></a>

          <input type="text" id="pizza-title" name="pizza-title" placeholder="title"><br>
          <input type="text" id="pizza-recipe" name="pizza-recipe" placeholder="recipe"><br>

          <label for="vegy1">Cucumber</label>
          <input type="number" class="quant" name="vegy1" data-name="cucumber" min="0" max="3" value="0">

          <label for="vegy2">Tomato</label>
          <input type="number" class="quant" name="vegy2" data-name="tomato" min="0" max="3" value="0">

          <label for="vegy3">Pineapple</label>
          <input type="number" class="quant" name="vegy3" data-name="pineapple" min="0" max="3" value="0">

          <label for="vegy4">Avocado</label>
          <input type="number" class="quant" name="vegy4" data-name="avocado" min="0" max="3" value="0"><br>

          <label for="vegy5">Eggplant</label>
          <input type="number" class="quant" name="vegy5" data-name="eggplant" min="0" max="3" value="0">

          <label for="vegy6">Olive</label>
          <input type="number" class="quant" name="vegy6" data-name="olive" min="0" max="3" value="0">

          <label for="vegy7">Onion</label>
          <input type="number" class="quant" name="vegy7" data-name="onion" min="0" max="3" value="0">

          <label for="vegy8">Mushroom</label>
          <input type="number" class="quant" name="vegy8" data-name="mushroom" min="0" max="3" value="0"><br>

          <label for="vegy9">Garlic</label>
          <input type="number" class="quant" name="vegy9" data-name="garlic" min="0" max="3" value="0">

          <label for="vegy10">Spinach</label>
          <input type="number" class="quant" name="vegy10" data-name="spinach" min="0" max="3" value="0">

          <label for="vegy11">Cilantro</label>
          <input type="number" class="quant" name="vegy11" data-name="cilantro" min="0" max="3" value="0">

          <label for="vegy12">Chicken</label>
          <input type="number" class="quant" name="vegy12" data-name="chicken" min="0" max="3" value="0"><br>

          <label for="vegy13">Anchovy</label>
          <input type="number" class="quant" name="vegy13" data-name="anchovy" min="0" max="3" value="0">

          <label for="vegy14">Bacon</label>
          <input type="number" class="quant" name="vegy14" data-name="bacon" min="0" max="3" value="0">

          <label for="vegy15">Sausage</label>
          <input type="number" class="quant" name="vegy15" data-name="sausage" min="0" max="3" value="0">

          <label for="vegy16">Beef</label>
          <input type="number" class="quant" name="vegy16" data-name="beef" min="0" max="3" value="0"><br>

          <label for="vegy17">Ham</label>
          <input type="number" class="quant" name="vegy17" data-name="ham" min="0" max="3" value="0">

          <label for="vegy18">Pepperoni</label>
          <input type="number" class="quant" name="vegy18" data-name="pepperoni" min="0" max="3" value="0">

          <label for="vegy19">Salami</label>
          <input type="number" class="quant" name="vegy19" data-name="salami" min="0" max="3" value="0">

          <label for="vegy20">Banana</label>
          <input type="number" class="quant" name="vegy20" data-name="banana" min="0" max="3" value="0"><br>

          <p id="totalCal"></p>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary addPizza">Add Recipe</button>
          </div>

        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working fiddle of your code, in the future add one whenever is possible

https://codepen.io/rodozlatan/pen/aXvqag

Can you explain better from there what is the part that is not working as expected?

```
<button id="button" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="Add a recipe">Add a recipe</button>
<!-- end of button -->

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">New Recipe</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form class="recipe-form" action="/pizza" method="POST">
          <a id="userId" data-id="1"></a>

          <input type="text" id="pizza-title" name="pizza-title" placeholder="title"><br>
          <input type="text" id="pizza-recipe" name="pizza-recipe" placeholder="recipe"><br>

          <label for="vegy1">Cucumber</label>
          <input type="number" class="quant" name="vegy1" data-name="cucumber" min="0" max="3" value="0">

          <label for="vegy2">Tomato</label>
          <input type="number" class="quant" name="vegy2" data-name="tomato" min="0" max="3" value="0">

          <label for="vegy3">Pineapple</label>
          <input type="number" class="quant" name="vegy3" data-name="pineapple" min="0" max="3" value="0">

          <label for="vegy4">Avocado</label>
          <input type="number" class="quant" name="vegy4" data-name="avocado" min="0" max="3" value="0"><br>

          <label for="vegy5">Eggplant</label>
          <input type="number" class="quant" name="vegy5" data-name="eggplant" min="0" max="3" value="0">

          <label for="vegy6">Olive</label>
          <input type="number" class="quant" name="vegy6" data-name="olive" min="0" max="3" value="0">

          <label for="vegy7">Onion</label>
          <input type="number" class="quant" name="vegy7" data-name="onion" min="0" max="3" value="0">

          <label for="vegy8">Mushroom</label>
          <input type="number" class="quant" name="vegy8" data-name="mushroom" min="0" max="3" value="0"><br>

          <label for="vegy9">Garlic</label>
          <input type="number" class="quant" name="vegy9" data-name="garlic" min="0" max="3" value="0">

          <label for="vegy10">Spinach</label>
          <input type="number" class="quant" name="vegy10" data-name="spinach" min="0" max="3" value="0">

          <label for="vegy11">Cilantro</label>
          <input type="number" class="quant" name="vegy11" data-name="cilantro" min="0" max="3" value="0">

          <label for="vegy12">Chicken</label>
          <input type="number" class="quant" name="vegy12" data-name="chicken" min="0" max="3" value="0"><br>

          <label for="vegy13">Anchovy</label>
          <input type="number" class="quant" name="vegy13" data-name="anchovy" min="0" max="3" value="0">

          <label for="vegy14">Bacon</label>
          <input type="number" class="quant" name="vegy14" data-name="bacon" min="0" max="3" value="0">

          <label for="vegy15">Sausage</label>
          <input type="number" class="quant" name="vegy15" data-name="sausage" min="0" max="3" value="0">

          <label for="vegy16">Beef</label>
          <input type="number" class="quant" name="vegy16" data-name="beef" min="0" max="3" value="0"><br>

          <label for="vegy17">Ham</label>
          <input type="number" class="quant" name="vegy17" data-name="ham" min="0" max="3" value="0">

          <label for="vegy18">Pepperoni</label>
          <input type="number" class="quant" name="vegy18" data-name="pepperoni" min="0" max="3" value="0">

          <label for="vegy19">Salami</label>
          <input type="number" class="quant" name="vegy19" data-name="salami" min="0" max="3" value="0">

          <label for="vegy20">Banana</label>
          <input type="number" class="quant" name="vegy20" data-name="banana" min="0" max="3" value="0"><br>

          <p id="totalCal"></p>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary addPizza">Add Recipe</button>
          </div>

        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So my problem is that I am using a .ejs file not .html file so that is why bootstrap is not working with the modal and labels?